# Updating Wordpress Password after migration causes login error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, md5

This is weird, probably a lack of knowledge about hashing but there is an issue I've seen in a couple of wordpress projects:

After migrating a wordpress site from localhost to a commercial hosting any update of migrated users' password made in the new server will make the site (in the new server of course) not to recognize the new password.This happens only with users created in the previous server.

At first I try it throught the settings option in the admin panel, after the session is killed I'm asked to introduce the new password but I get the incorrect password error.

So I get into de db and edit the field with Md5 (first essay from a terminal, second from phpmyadmin), but when I try to login I got the same error. It seems like something is different in the hashing process between the servers. Which if right it's cool and safier but not explained in any wp document I've read and a problem if you lost or try to update your password with a previous backup. I didn't change any key in wp-config or any other bite in wp's core.

The only way I was able to login again was to copy/paste the old password (generated in the local era , when it was on localhost) from the last backup.

As expected the output of MD5'ing any string it's the same in both servers (I felt stupid just for trying it but what else). And as I said before, new users wont face this issue just the migrated ones.

What could be possibly going on?

Comment: md5 is a hash function, it's not an "encoding". encoding refers to the text format, e.g. utf8, ascii.

Comment: #misprint Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Migrating WordPress users with their password is easily possible with this [WordPress user import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the actual database with an English version of the password, the built in login script will accept that and rehash it for future use. That is part of their password recovery. Once you change it in the database simply login and you should be good to go.